# I'm worried I've accidentally deleted Windows!

Tags: dell, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu, and I installed it on a separate partition. For some reason though, I don't get the OS choices menu. I spoke to a friend about it; he said that Ubuntu shouldn't have deleted Windows (and everything on that drive) because I put it on a separate partition.

Have I done something wrong?  Is Windows gone forever?  Or have I made a mistake so my OS menu choices won't show?

I didn't select the replace Windows option, I definitely installed it on a separate partition.  Also, I can't check my Windows OS disk c: via my Ubuntu partition, is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see your Windows partition from Ubuntu.  However, please provide the exact details of how you did the installation.  Did you boot into the DVD or did you use the DVD with Windows running?  If you installed from within Windows, disregard the next part of the question.

To find out what is happening, you might open up the disk utility in Ubuntu.  This will show you exactly what drives and partitions you have.  Windows XP and 7 are on a NTFS partition.  If there isn't one, it is fairly certain you have somehow deleted the Windows partition.

Please give us a bit more information so we can offer better suggestions.  Please tell us which version of Windows are you using?  Which version of Ubuntu?  And what did you actually do (step by step)?

Comment: If windows drive and files are there just run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Where do I find the disk utility?

Comment: Click on the folder icon of the dash. In left hand side you can see the drives. Check whether 7 drive is there or not

Comment: To run the Disk Utility you can either (1) search for *disk* in Dash or (2) enter the command `palimpsest` in a terminal window. Another alternative is to enter the command `sudo fdisk -l` into a terminal and then copy the output and add it to your question by editing it. (If you're not sure how to edit your question see the **[faq#howtoask]**)